# How to enrich Oauth2 authentication with data from database?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I use spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client with webflux (spring boot 2.2.0.M3).

I'd like that my controller methods got Principal data with userId from database.

I realized that i should implement ReactiveUserDetailsService, ReactiveUserDetailsPasswordService to authenticate user with login and password.

Also I'd like that I can authenticate same user from google and facebook accounts by email.

What interfaces I should to implement to achieve seamless authentication
for same user by email/password, facebook, google accounts?

By default in my controller methods I have different Principal objects for Oauth2 authentication and UserDetails authentication

Answer (score 0):

This answer is by going on the assumption that at a time only one authentication provider mechanism will be used and not all together. 
To achieve this goal, you have to Autowire authentication manager in Authorization Server Configuration. This authentication manager bean will be conditional. You can mention in an external application.properties file that which authentication mechanism has to be used. Then suppose you want to facebook as the authentication provider the create a class whose code would look like this

```
public class FacebookAuthenticationProvider{

@Autowired
AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;

@Override
public void configure(){
        auth.authenticationProvider(/**add desired authentication provider here**/);
   }
}
```

Similary for google, LDAP etc can be done. So whenever spring applications starts, authentication provider provider in external property file will be used while configuring Authorization Server.